# Build a dynamic expression with nested OR between many ANDS

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, predicate

I am trying to build an expression like the one below dynamically.

```
SomeList.Where(person => person.firstname == "foo" && 
              (person.lastanme == "bar" ||person.middleName == "bar") && 
               person.age == 65)
```

I'm using a class called [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) :

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T> ()  { return f => true;  }
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T> () { return f => false; }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                      Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.OrElse (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                       Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.AndAlso (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }
}
```

I first verify if properties of a search object are filled out, if they are then I call a method that builds a predicate based on that property.  Then I add all these to a list of predicates.  At the end I go through and append all of the predicates together in the list with the PredicateBuilder.And() method.

However I need to be able to filter off of two different properties as in last name OR middle name.

I would like an example of how to dynamically build these predicates and insert an or between them when necessary, or a suggestion for a better overall design to meet my needs.

In the code below I call CreatePredicate().

```
    private  static List<Expression<Func<DirectoryEntry,bool>>> _conditionsList = new List<Expression<Func<DirectoryEntry,bool>>>();
    public static Expression<Func<DirectoryEntry, bool>> CreatePredicate(DirectorySearchData searchData)
    {
        _conditionsList.Clear();

        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<DirectoryEntry>();

        AddFirstNameCondition(searchData);
        AddLastNameCondition(searchData);
        AddUsernameCondition(searchData);

        predicate = BuilPredicateFromConditionList(predicate);

        return predicate;
    }

private static void AddFirstNameCondition(DirectorySearchData searchData)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchData.FirstName))
        {
            _conditionsList.Add(entry => entry.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(searchData.FirstName.ToLower()));
        }
    }

    private static void AddLastNameCondition(DirectorySearchData searchData)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchData.LastName))
        {
            _conditionsList.Add(entry => entry.LastName.ToLower().Contains(searchData.LastName.ToLower()));
        }
    }

    private static void AddUsernameCondition(DirectorySearchData searchData)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchData.UserName))
        {
            _conditionsList.Add(entry => entry.Username.ToLower().Contains(searchData.UserName.ToLower()));
        }
    }

private static Expression<Func<DirectoryEntry, bool>> BuilPredicateFromConditionList(Expression<Func<DirectoryEntry, bool>> predicate)
    {
        if (_conditionsList == null || _conditionsList.Count <= 0) return predicate;

        predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<DirectoryEntry>();
        foreach (var condition in _conditionsList)
        {
            predicate = PredicateBuilder.And(predicate, condition);
        }
        return predicate;
    }

    public class DirectorySearchData
{

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string CampusPhone { get; set; }
    public string CampusAddress { get; set; }
    public string CampusBox { get; set; }
    public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
    public string HomeState { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentOrOffice { get; set; }
    public string StudentMajor { get; set; }
    public string Concentration { get; set; }
    public string SgaCabinetPositionName { get; set; }
    public string Hiatus { get; set; }
    public string StudentClass { get; set; }

    public DirectorySearchData()
    {
        LastName = "";
        FirstName = "";
        UserName = "";
        CampusPhone = "";
        CampusAddress = "";
        CampusBox = "";
        HomeAddress = "";
        HomeState = "";
        DepartmentOrOffice = "";
        StudentMajor = "";
        Concentration = "";
        SgaCabinetPositionName = "";
        Hiatus = "";
        StudentClass = "";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `person.firstname = "foo"` or `person.firstname == "foo"`? First correct your static code before building dynamic expressions ;)

Comment: HAHA thanks, i was just typing a little too fast :)

Comment: Please note that => is the lambda operator! Your "example" contains four (and thus makes no sense) but only one is necessary like this: 
(p => (p.a || p.b) && p.c)

Comment: user1890202, Yes sorry about that i have edited the example, did i mention im new to lamdas and linq :).  Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For create more complexity expression you can use more complexity expression in `Add*Condition` methods. For build `OR` expression in your case you can use next method:

```
private static void AddLastNameOrMiddleNameCondition(DirectorySearchData searchData)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchData.LastName))
  {
    var lastNameOrMiddleName = PredicateBuilder.Or(
      (DirectorySearchData entry) => entry.LastName.ToLower().Contains(searchData.LastName.ToLower()),
      (DirectorySearchData entry) => entry.MiddleName.ToLower().Contains(searchData.MiddleName.ToLower()));

    _conditionsList.Add(lastNameOrMiddleName);
  }
}
```

**Upd:** or more сleaner example:

```
private static void AddLastNameOrMiddleNameCondition(DirectorySearchData searchData)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchData.LastName))
  {
    var inner = PredicateBuilder.New<DirectorySearchData>(false);
    // BTW, Use New<T> insted of PredicateBuilder.False<DirectorySearchData>(); methods False<T> and True<T> are obsolete.
    inner = inner.Or(entry => entry.LastName.ToLower().Contains(searchData.LastName.ToLower()));
    inner = inner.Or(entry => entry.MiddleName.ToLower().Contains(searchData.MiddleName.ToLower()));

    _conditionsList.Add(inner);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the PredicateBuilder class your referring to the same as the one i mentioned above or is it from another source?

Comment: @Mike, From your source, I'm using LinqKik 1.1.8.0 version. Versions less than 1.1.7.1 are not included `New` and `New<T>` methods, in this versions just use `PredicateBuilder.False<DirectorySearchData>()`.

Comment: Thanks so much, your answer helped me figure out what i was missing!  I'm obviously new to building out lambda expressions so i very much appreciate your time and help!